# jQuery TextFX plugin (not the textfx 2), how to make it animate multiline?

Tags: jquery, animation, text

My client bought this plugin for text animation 
http://www.codingjack.com/textfx/

and wants me to make it work for multi-line paragraph keeping all the styling of the text.
Has someone encountered that and may be you would suggest a solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no good way of doing that besides reusing plugin for each line which is obviously not a responsive solution. If you have a fixed width for the text container then you will do it only on your media query breakpoints.

The multiline plugin Textfx2 was not doing exactly what you would naturally imagine, “you give a block of long text and it animates”. It is much more like configured for reusing the one-line solution for each line. So you anyway need to configure many “one lines” by the end of the day. 
Think carefully before buying these plugins.